# Not able to push value to foreign key in .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following Fluent API. However, I am unable to automatically push the primary key `RegistrationID` from the first table (`Incidence`) to the foreign key `RegistrationID` of the second table (`AssignedRoles`).

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AssignedRoles>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.AssignedRolesID)
                .HasName("PK_dbo.AssignedRoles");

            entity.HasIndex(e => e.RegistrationID, "IX_RegistrationID");

            entity.Property(e => e.AssignedRolesID).HasColumnName("AssignedRolesID");

            entity.Property(e => e.RegistrationID).HasColumnName("RegistrationID");

            entity.HasOne(s => s.Incidence)
            .WithMany(g => g.AssignedRoles)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.RegistrationID)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
        });

           modelBuilder.Entity<Incidence>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.RegistrationID)
                .HasName("PK_dbo.Incidence");

            entity.ToTable("Incidence");

            entity.Property(e => e.RegistrationID).HasColumnName("RegistrationID").ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.TicketUser).HasDefaultValueSql("((0))");

            entity.Property(e => e.TSCNO).HasColumnName("TSCNO");
        });
```

Any advice on where I may be misfiring?

Comment: Hi @Nickson, what do you mean for `push the primary key RegistrationID from the first table (Incidence) to the foreign key `? What's the error message you receive? If you do any operation for database and makes error, pls also share enough code.

Comment: @Rena There is a relationship between Table A and Table B but on saving data, the database generated value on Table A's primary key isn't pushed to Table B rather the value 0 is the one assigned

Comment: Hi @Nickson, So could you pls share your model design and share the code about how do you do database operation?